# Не могу сделать задачу (Python)

Tags: python, классы

Читаю книгу A Byte of Python. На странице 149 дана задача. Сама задача : "Создайте собственную программу «Адресная книга», работающую из командной строки и позволяющую просматривать, добавлять, изменять, удалять или искать контактные
данные ваших знакомых. Кроме того, эта информация также должна сохраняться на диске для последующего доступа."

Я решил сделать эту задачу так : Создать класс, при создании объект, объект будет добавляться в словарь.

Код :

```
class Adress_book():
    '''Класс адрессной книгой'''

    def __init__(self, name, numberphone):
        self.name = name
        self.numberphone = numberphone
        print('Создан контакт {0} под номером {1}'.format(self.name, self.numberphone))
        ab = {self.name : self.numberphone}
        print(ab)

    def info(self):
        print(ab)

contact1 = Adress_book('Michael', '+91049201450')
contact2 = Adress_book('Bella', '+39849220110')

contact1.info()
```

В консоли мне выходит ошибка :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "(мой путь)", line 17, in <module>
    contact1.info()
  File "(мой путь)", line 12, in info
    print(ab)
NameError: name 'ab' is not defined. Did you mean: 'abs'?
```

Не могу понять, почему не выходит так, как я задумывал. Можете помочь, и объяснить в чём проблема

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У вас `ab` - это локальная переменная метода `__init__()`. Соответственно, метод `info()` ничего о ней не знает. Да она к тому же перестаёт существовать по окончанию работы функции `__init__()`.
Чтобы передавать её между методами класса, сделайте её атрибутом класса, т.е. работайте с `self.ab` вместо `ab`.